# Fixed variable with linq query inside for loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, for-loop

I have an issue with a linq query I am currently trying to get the correct value from to populate a table. My for loop saves values to the database on each iteration but the query does not bring back the correct results when I use breakpoints to view the value of the variable. My initial values are(10, 20, 10, 12) and on each iteration I want them to subtract by 3 and save the new value to the database which is working correctly however when I query these values in my linq query it still brings back the initial values of (10, 20, 10, 12) on each iteration, How can I get the correct values back from the database?

```
for (int a = 0; a < copy; a++ )
        {
          var qtyRemaining = from row in db.ShipmentPackagesRemaining
                               where row.orderid.Equals(salesNum) && row.itemnumber == shipItemNum
                               select row;

            orderQty = qtyRemaining.First().qty_remaining;

            // loop through items in package
            if(orderRecord.qtyPerPack > 0)
            {
                if(orderRecord.qtyPerPack > orderQty)
                {
                    packQty = orderQty;
                }
                else
                {
                    packQty = orderRecord.qtyPerPack;
                }

                if (shipPackCheck.Count() == 0)
                {
                    // populate database for shipment packages
                    shipmentPack.id = shipPackId;
                    shipmentPack.shipmentid = shipNo.First().shipmentid;
                    shipmentPack.shipmenttype = "SO";
                    shipmentPack.partid = "Pack_Type1";
                    shipmentPack.grossweight = 0;
                    shipmentPack.nettweight = 0;
                    shipmentPack.actualweight = 0;
                    shipmentPack.olversionnumber = countQty;

                    db.shipmentpackages.Add(shipmentPack);
                }

                // populate shipment package items
                shipmentPackItem.packageid = shipPackId;
                shipmentPackItem.itemnumber = itemNo;
                shipmentPackItem.shipmentid = shipNo.First().shipmentid;
                shipmentPackItem.shipmentitemnumber = shipItemNum;
                shipmentPackItem.shipmenttype = "SO";
                shipmentPackItem.stockbatchid = stockBatchID;
                shipmentPackItem.quantity = packQty;
                shipmentPackItem.uom = partDetails.First().uom;
                shipmentPackItem.weight = partDetails.First().weight;
                shipmentPackItem.olversionnumber = 0;

                db.shipmentpackageitems.Add(shipmentPackItem);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

}

Comment: which EF version you are using?

Comment: check the tables you are reading from and writing to. Are you updating the source table(s)?

Comment: During each iteration I am using a breakpoint to pause the program and checking the table in sql, all data is as it should be, just doesnt seem to return this as a new instance inside the loop. Using EF 4.5.1

Comment: create new DataContext for each request to Database, because EF cache all data which you using.

Comment: @Lance Thanks, that fixed my problem